# how to set different price or discount for each user with the same product in woocommerce wordpress php?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to create table on the database to set how much is the discount for each user.

Table user_discount

```
 -------------------------
|user | product_id | disc |
 -------------------------
| A   | 1          | $1   |
 -------------------------
| B   | 1          | $2   |
 -------------------------
| C   | 1          | $1   |
 -------------------------
| A   | 2          | $2   |
--------------------------
```

So, when user go to checkout page, the price will subtract with the discount value from table discount for each product that match in the cart.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using membership plugin, anyone. There are a number of plugins available for this purpose. So you will define membership type, any user which will be eligible for a discounted rate under that membership type, will get the relevant discount.

Comment: So you might will write some logic and queries in functions.php to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, i will.
PHP and some queries
i have done some code using php in function.php, but it is not dealing with woocommerce meta data. it's only reading some data from the table i create

Comment: If you are inserting product id as a separate column in your table, it can work as a foreign key. Are you already working like this? It will help you to keep synchronized your table.